# How to deal with blank cells on an IF (OR) statement

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a formula that works, but my problem is with column G.

If the cell is blank in column G then it returns *#VALUE*.

Does anyone know of a simple way I can fix this?

The formula is below:

`=IF(OR(L$3 < $G4,L$3 > $H4-1,$D4="None"),0,IF($D4="Once",IF(L$3=$G4,$F4,0),IF($D4="Daily",$J4,IF($D4="Weekly",$J4,IF($D4="Monthly",$J4,IF($D4="Quarterly",$J4))))))`

Many thanks!

Comment: it shouldn't give you an error message. select a cell giving you error, then go to formulas - evaluate formula, then pressing "evaluate" you can follow step by step how it calculates. It probably will help you to identify the issue. If not, then please update your question with information where it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jatulle is correct wrapping it in in a iferror will work and is a complete answer. 
However, it will also mask any other error that occurs in any of the nesting formulas. This may or may not be to your liking.

A different way to do the wrapping if is to put a check for a blank in the front.

- if($g4="","", {Rest of original formula },"")

in from of the formula so that is $g4 is empty the cell stays blank.
If I have multiple cells and want to make it only when all have values then I use a OR such as

- if(or($g4="",L$3=""),{Rest of original formula },"")

Lastly, if I will be using this in multiple places I will convert it to a name [using the name manager on the ribbon]

- Valid=or($g4="",L$3)

then it would be used as

- If(Valid,{Rest of original formula },"")

I prefer using a  name like Valid instead of or($g4="") easier to work with later if I need to modify something.

Lastly, I kept using $g4="" instead of isblank($g4). ISblank could be used if it reads better for you.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading this, but after your 1st bullet, the logic seems reversed.  Also, the 3rd bullet looks incomplete.

Comment: first bullet, logic is if blank, then blank cell else continue with original formula

Comment: 3rd bullet is just for the logic in the Valid for making a name, then the 4th bullet uses the valid made in the 3rd bullet,  I would also make others called once, daily, etc to cut down on the long nested if loops looking semi-unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole formula with `IFERROR( anything , "value if error" )` like so:

`=IFERROR(IF(OR(L$3 < $G4,L$3 > $H4-1,$D4="None"),0,IF($D4="Once",IF(L$3=$G4,$F4,0),IF($D4="Daily",$J4,IF($D4="Weekly",$J4,IF($D4="Monthly",$J4,IF($D4="Quarterly",$J4)))))), "" )`